# AWS charges for RDS even withno db instances

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I accidentally created a database instance of a paid tier in AWS. However, I deleted the instance as soon as I created it. I am still getting charged for some services. Will they go away soon or is there something I need to do further. If you require more pictures I will attach them. Please please help me get rid of these costs. I have no clue how to cancel these costs. Any guidance will be appreciated. [image: This is the picture I see when I go to cost details][image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any snapshots of it? Go to RDS console and check for snapshots.

Comment: I dont have any snapshots for the service. It is saying that I am using 'Amazon Relational Database Service (Ohio)'. It is charging me very minimal amounts. However, I want to disable it completely.

Comment: It writes you are charged for backup storage. If you don't have snapshots now, this maybe for the period when you had it?

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking. However, I disabled it last month itself and now it is showing estimated charges for August. Shall I post a picture of that as well for you? Also, thank you for taking time to help me I really appreciate it

Comment: You double checked your `Snapshots` and `Automated backups ` in RDS console? If its empty it this region (make sure you check correct region), them maybe have to contact AWS support.

Comment: My snapshots and automated backups showed 1 entry in both. However, I had deleted them also. Should I not have done that? in fact I deleted them today morning itself. I thought maybe that would stop the backup charges. So maybe it'll will stop charging me from next month?

Comment: If you deleted them today, then they will have some cost up until now. Bills are ones per month, so next build it should clear.

Comment: I have uploaded another picture. Do I need to delete anything else for the billing to stop?

Comment: I think this is more of a AWS support question than a programming question.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question here. I had used this service for connecting a db with Django, which is why I thought that I should ask it here.